# How to change json value in a nested (mongoose) callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongoose

I'd like to change a json array within a nested function that I created as a callback within a mongoose query.

I am puzzled why it is not possible to change a json array within this scope. Any attempt results in the original value of 'default' which can be shown by the last `console.log(answer)`

As I am an Embedded C developer with newbie skills in javascript (at most), I'd like to know how to alter any value in a nested scope. And please share some background why my function shows this type of behaviour.

Any help is warmly welcome...

```js
function pwdGen(body) {
  var answer = [{
    error: errors["E004"],
    user: '',
    password: 'default',
    timeout: 0,
    active: false
  }];
    user.find().where("usertype").equals("superuser").select("username password").exec(
      function (err, users) {
        if(users.isArray && users.length==0) {
          console.log("exists");
          answer[0].password="exist_pwd";
        } else {
          console.log("empty");
          answer[0].password="empty_pwd";
        }
      }
    );
    answer[0].user="asdave"
    answer[0].timeout=1;
    console.log(answer);
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: I think there are syntax error(s) in your code: `Array.isArray(users)` for checking if it's an array https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Comment: Oh right, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

Javascript is [async](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff) in nature means it *does not* execute instructions such as network access synchronously like C, C++ or Java.

**Solution**

[Promises](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) are here for rescue.

You need to do something like this:

```
var users = user.find().where("usertype").equals("superuser").select("username password").exec();

users.then(function(user) {

        if(users.isArray && users.length==0) {
          console.log("exists");
          answer[0].password="exist_pwd";
        } else {
          console.log("empty");
          answer[0].password="empty_pwd";
        }      
})
```

**EDIT**

It's just that the JS is single threaded means one thing at a time but when it sees any network access request like API call, it moves that instruction to somewhere else in the browser where its gets executed and JS continue with the following instructions when all instructions are executed, the moved part which was executed somewhere else, it's result get merged.

Excellent [resource](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) to get the idea.

Comment: Oh, I got it - so that means I just defined the callback and it is executed in a different context!?